# Picture Won't Show When Qt App Deployed to Android Device

Tags: android, c++, qt

I have a c++ program written in Qt Creator 3.1.2 that loads a .jpg from an absolute file path. Upon deploying to an android device, the program no longer finds the file. How can I send the picture to the device during the build? Also, how can I make a dynamic file path that will just look in the local directory for the files?

Thanks

Comment: If your pictures belongs to your program, you should look at the [Qt resource system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html)

Comment: Through your link I was able to figure it out. Thanks.